# O que são Especificações, Frameworks e Interfaces?

Tags: java, aplicação-web

Recentemente comecei a estudar e pesquisar um pouco sobre Java EE, e alguns dos termos que mais aparecem são:

- Especificações
- Frameworks
- e Interfaces

Li algumas coisas sobre, mas ainda estou confuso.
Alguém explicar de forma simples e prática o que são e suas funções?